# project->peoperties->debugging->Command Arguments does't work in VS community 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I see the command line argument (coreProgram.txt) in the properties pages but the it is not recognized in the program i.e.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
```

does not recognize `argv[1]` is in fact `argc = 1`

Comment: arrays are zero-indexed in C++, the first element would be `argv[0]`. but this argument is typically the path of the command, so your command line argument is actually probably not used anyways, but this explains why `argc == 1`

Comment: the complete code outputs argv[0]

Comment: the complete code returns argv[0] -> the program name but argc = 1 and ther is nothing in argv[1]

Comment: what i remember from visual studio is vague, but are you sure you selected the correct target in the settings?

Comment: Make sure the right configuration is selected. If you are in debug mode it make take you to configuration for release mode, vice versa.